# authentication issue Laravel 5.2 login only working locally

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, cookies, ubuntu-16.04

i'm new with the laravel framework and i'm trying to implement my own small CMS for my one-page personal website. I'm using laravel 5.2 with the standard authentication created by: `php artisan make:auth`. Locally everything is working fine. The problem occurs on the live environment (Ubuntu server 16.04) when I try to login. I’m getting the following stack traces:

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:
1.  in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67
2.  at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
3.  at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
4.  at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
5.  at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
6.  at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
7.  at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
8.  at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
9.  at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
10. at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
11. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
12. at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
13. at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
14. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
15. at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
16. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
17. at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
18. at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
19. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
20. at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
21. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
22. at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
23. at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
24. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
25. at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
26. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
27. at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
28. at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 726
29. at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 699
30. at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
31. at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
32. at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
33. at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
34. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
35. at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
36. at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
37. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
38. at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
39. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
40. at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
41. at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
42. at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
43. at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

```
ErrorException in Filesystem.php line 109:file_put_contents(/8c52f42d0453d6f2bbd07ea1aa65b77b90238995): failed to open stream: Permission denied
1.  in Filesystem.php line 109
2.  at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'file_put_contents(/8c52f42d0453d6f2bbd07ea1aa65b77b90238995): failed to open stream: Permission denied', '/var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php', '109', array('path' => '/8c52f42d0453d6f2bbd07ea1aa65b77b90238995', 'contents' => 'a:3:{s:6:"_token";s:40:"Z5yxi65ubXWtVrZiMeU2yAGdJjxQs4xxNY7xU5Tx";s:9:"_sf2_meta";a:3:{s:1:"u";i:1473341363;s:1:"c";i:1473341363;s:1:"l";s:1:"0";}s:5:"flash";a:2:{s:3:"old";a:0:{}s:3:"new";a:0:{}}}', 'lock' => true))
3.  at file_put_contents('/8c52f42d0453d6f2bbd07ea1aa65b77b90238995', 'a:3:{s:6:"_token";s:40:"Z5yxi65ubXWtVrZiMeU2yAGdJjxQs4xxNY7xU5Tx";s:9:"_sf2_meta";a:3:{s:1:"u";i:1473341363;s:1:"c";i:1473341363;s:1:"l";s:1:"0";}s:5:"flash";a:2:{s:3:"old";a:0:{}s:3:"new";a:0:{}}}', '2') in Filesystem.php line 109
4.  at Filesystem->put('/8c52f42d0453d6f2bbd07ea1aa65b77b90238995', 'a:3:{s:6:"_token";s:40:"Z5yxi65ubXWtVrZiMeU2yAGdJjxQs4xxNY7xU5Tx";s:9:"_sf2_meta";a:3:{s:1:"u";i:1473341363;s:1:"c";i:1473341363;s:1:"l";s:1:"0";}s:5:"flash";a:2:{s:3:"old";a:0:{}s:3:"new";a:0:{}}}', true) inFileSessionHandler.php line 71
5.  at FileSessionHandler->write('8c52f42d0453d6f2bbd07ea1aa65b77b90238995', 'a:3:{s:6:"_token";s:40:"Z5yxi65ubXWtVrZiMeU2yAGdJjxQs4xxNY7xU5Tx";s:9:"_sf2_meta";a:3:{s:1:"u";i:1473341363;s:1:"c";i:1473341363;s:1:"l";s:1:"0";}s:5:"flash";a:2:{s:3:"old";a:0:{}s:3:"new";a:0:{}}}') in Store.php line 262
6.  at Store->save() in StartSession.php line 88
7.  at StartSession->terminate(object(Request), object(Response)) in Kernel.php line 155
8.  at Kernel->terminate(object(Request), object(Response)) in index.php line 58
```

Here are my routes

```
Route::get('/', 'FrontendController@index');

       Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
            Route::auth();
            Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index');
            Route::get('/profile', 'AdminController@editProfile');
            Route::put('/profile/update', 'AdminController@updateProfile');
            Route::get('/page', 'PageController@index');
            Route::put('/page/update', 'PageController@update');
            Route::resource('aboutItems', 'AboutItemsController');
            Route::resource('portfolioItems', 'PortfolioItemsController');
    });
```

The login form:

```
 <div class="login login-v2" data-pageload-addclass="animated fadeIn">
            <div class="login-content">
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
                    {!! csrf_field() !!}

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">

                            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">

                            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                <i class="fa fa-btn"></i>Login
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Things that I did/tried and looked into:

- Directories within the storage and the bootstrap/cache are writable
  and set to www-data
- Generated a new key with php artisan key:generate
  Made sure the login form is sending a csrf token by adding {!! Csrf_field() !!}
- At one point I even tried to set permissions to 777 for the whole project, without result
- Tested if session is being set properly
- Tried to change the session config to cookie instead of a file
- Cleared cache, composer dump-autoload, deleted any cookies
- Database is seeded

Comment: Are you sure the csrf field is generated? check elements using chrome f11. there should be a hidden field.

Comment: Yes there is. The field is being generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded my project to 5.3 and now everything seems to be working fine on my VPS. I still don't know what the actual problem was. Maybe something went wrong while installing Laravel or the authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I used csrf field like following way in my view file just below to form tag.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}" />
```

Try this, Hope this will help.

Comment: Like I said, the crsf field is properly being generated. Changing it to your example does not resolve the issue unfortunately.

Comment: Is your form contains input fields? if yes you should use token like I write here, try once.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear in my response. I did try your method. It did not work.